How to pass product dimensions (width, height, length) to DHL in Magento 2.4?
I am using Magento 2.4.6. I want to pass the dimensions of my products (width, height, length) to DHL. Actually only weight is passed to DHL.
Is there a way to achieve this in Magento 2.4? I've already connect Magento to a DHL access token and it works.
